# google contacts not shown

Tags: contacts

When I log onto GMail on my HTC Desire, I can't find a way to access my GMail contacts. I read that there was some link on the left of the screen. I see none. I am now at a loss

Comment: Make sure your GMail contacts are syncing to the phone. Menu -> Settings -> Accounts & sync -> [your account name] and see if a box next to "Sync Contacts" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

The Gmail app does not have a contacts section -- you only see you contacts when typing in the To field or whatever.  You should have a Contacts app with your Gmail contacts, if you are syncing them.  To change your sync settings, look in `Settings -> Accounts and sync`.

If you're referring to the website, that's not an Android question.  But the mobile website doesn't have Contacts on the left, you have to view the Full site (there's a link at the bottom of the mobile view).